# Powershellのリモーティングにおいて起動したmongo shellがすぐ終了してしまう

Tags: powershell, mongodb

Mongodb初心者です。
MongodbをインストールしたWindow Server (2016 Standard)のpowershellでmongoシェルを起動すると以下のように問題なく使えます

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.11
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("292078ce-619a-496c-aa8e-cd898b40e75c") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.11
Server has startup warnings:
2020-02-18T17:15:22.645+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-02-18T17:15:22.645+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-02-18T17:15:22.645+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-02-18T17:15:22.645+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring() 
---
```

警告が表示されるものの正常にshellが利用できます。

しかしこのサーバに別のPC（windows 10 enterprise)からpowershellのリモーティングで接続したのちにmongoシェルを起動しようとすると…

```
[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.11 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("30e82d49-14af-462f-8b26-404c25ddefc6") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.11
bye
```

このように、起動してすぐ終了してしまいます。
どこに問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1というIPアドレスは、ローカル・ループバック・アドレスと呼ばれる特殊なIPアドレスで、アクセスしているマシン自身を意味します。（ネットワークに出ることなく、データが戻ってくるのでloop backと呼ばれます）
MongodbをインストールしたWindow Server で、127.0.0.1:27017とアクセスすれば、そのWindows Serverの27017番ポートにアクセスすることになるので、mongodbが応答を返します。

windows 10のPCで、同じ127.0.0.1:27017にアクセスすれば、windows 10のPCの27017番ポートにアクセスすることになりますが、windows 10のPCではMongodbが稼働していないので、mongodbからの応答はありません。

windows 10のPCから、Window ServerのIPアドレスの27017番ポートのmongodbにアクセスすれば、ちゃんと応答が返ってくると思いますよ。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問の文面が至らなかったかもしれません。不具合状況をあらためて紹介します。window 10PCからmongodbが起動しているサーバにpowershellにてリモートログインした状態にてmongo shellを起動するとすぐ終了してしまします。windows 10 PC自体にはmongoはインストールされていません